# C# Guess A Number Game - How to make it work with Radio Buttons

Tags: c#, radio-button

Clearing the air now: yes, this is classwork. Don't want to be spoonfed an answer, just want to get some help understanding what I'm doing wrong and what I need to be doing instead.

First of all, for the sake of being clear, here is the prompt from the book:

> Create a project named GuessANumber with a Form that contains a guessing game with five RadioButtons numbered 1 through 5. Randomly choose one of the RadioButtons as the winning button. When the user clicks a RadioButton, display a message indicating whether the user is right.

And here is my best attempt at making it to these specs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GuessANumber
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random ran = new Random();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int randomNumber;
            randomNumber = ran.Next(0, 4);

            int correctAnswer = randomNumber;

            SelectButton(correctAnswer);
        }

        private void SelectButton(int correctAnswer)
        {
            bool guessedCorrectly;

            if (radioButton1.Checked && (Convert.ToInt32(radioButton1.Text) == correctAnswer))
            {
                guessedCorrectly = true;
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked && (Convert.ToInt32(radioButton2.Text) == correctAnswer))
            {
                guessedCorrectly = true;
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked && (Convert.ToInt32(radioButton3.Text) == correctAnswer))
            {
                guessedCorrectly = true;
            }
            else if (radioButton4.Checked && (Convert.ToInt32(radioButton4.Text) == correctAnswer))
            {
                guessedCorrectly = true;
            }
            else if (radioButton5.Checked && (Convert.ToInt32(radioButton5.Text) == correctAnswer))
            {
                guessedCorrectly = true;
            }
            else
            {
                guessedCorrectly = false;
            }

            if(guessedCorrectly == true)
            {
                winLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                loseLabel.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        private void hintLabel_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hintLabel.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
        }

        private void hintLabel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hintLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

My question, I guess, is this: how do I make this work as specified? I've gotten it to where I can make the labels for the win and lose conditions appear, so I know the part where I check for the win condition is working right, it's just that, being radio buttons, it defaults to 1 when the application starts. Is there a way I can make it so the radio buttons don't have a default?

**EDIT:** Mike's answer got me where I needed to be. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You are calling `SelectButton` on the form's constructor. Where is the user interaction there?

Comment: @MatiasCicero know it's iffy, but all I coded it to do is check which button is selected and check if it matches up with the correct answer. I was going to put it in a Click method for a Submit button, but as you can see in the prompt I have to do it "when a radio button is selected." I'm not sure what to use to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need wait until the user has selected one of the radio buttons, and then clicked some "OK" pushbutton.

So, begin by adding an "OK" pushbutton to your form, and adding a "buttonClicked" event handler for that pushbutton.

Once the user has clicked the "OK" pushbutton, you are supposed to check which radio button is selected, and then tell the user whether they made the correct choice or not.

By default, none of the radio buttons is selected after `InitializeComponent()`.  (And if by any chance one of them is selected it is rather simple to make them all unselected.)

Comment: I would really love to make it work upon clicking a button, but according to the prompt, I have to do it "when the user clicks a radio button." Is there some kind of event handler I can use to check for when that happens?

Comment: The specs don't mention an OK button.  While that might be more appropriate behavior, (s)he could also just handle the radio button click or check change event and the specs would be more accurately followed.  Pick the appropriate event from the radio button API.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh. Well, as far as I recall, radio buttons do issue a "buttonClicked" event, too.  So, you would be doing something like `radioButton1.Clicked += AnyRadioButtonClicked;` and then you would have a `private void AnyRadioButtonClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` method somewhere to handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

I would, personally, make an array that holds all 5 radio buttons.

```
RadioButton[] _buttons = { radioButton1, radioButton2, ..., radioButton5 };
```

Then I'd create a common event handler for the `Checked` event on all 5 radio buttons. It would look something like this:

```
void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_buttons[ran.Next(5)].Checked)
        // You win!
    else
        // You lose!
}
```